# Issue with getting transfer details

Tags: transactions, transfer

I'm trying to create something like solscan Token Transfers table for my token, like this:

[image: like this:]

I fetch transfers with logsSubscribe, but it returns like this:

{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"method": "logsNotification",
"params": {
"result": {
"context": {
"slot": 285187688
},
"value": {
"signature": "5vKUrLtJZ31sHt937DhBvKw6ciTzzBB7hNYFKxGzN7iBVimZ5QCzF7cRkPRkqQAvRghiHmxeNcX4AWnwiAbNhVsw",
"err": null,
"logs": [
"Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpINj.png)",
"Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
"Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpINj.png)",
"Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
"Program SW1TCH7qEPTdLsDHRgPuMQjbQxKdH2aBStViMFnt64f invoke [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpINj.png)",
"Program log: Instruction: AggregatorSaveResult",
"Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]",
"Program log: Instruction: Transfer",
"Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4736 of 258278 compute units",
"Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
"Program data: Dk7x7N2nVamjdokFdaa++3ClOmo2VJcejdN2ejwdTCWlI0gyCI0b7Wie/xAAAAAARd/yZQAAAAAKAAAAAAAAAA==",
"Program data: A5o8/ZicmX6jdokFdaa++3ClOmo2VJcejdN2ejwdTCWlI0gyCI0b7UQzLUYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJAAAAaJ7/EAAAAABF3/JlAAAAACdiSZSd8WPibtPO0qe9udGv2lY/3XQKaXRnpeHa0BnCAAAAAA==",
"Program data: TOkj7nevZ9ajdokFdaa++3ClOmo2VJcejdN2ejwdTCWlI0gyCI0b7QAAAAAAAAAAJ2JJlJ3xY+Ju087Sp7250a/aVj/ddAppdGel4drQGcLBxFiwAAAAAMHEWLAAAAAA",
"Program data: cB8z6WFkK/WjdokFdaa++3ClOmo2VJcejdN2ejwdTCWlI0gyCI0b7d2Hpm8bAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALAAAAaJ7/EAAAAABF3/JlAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
"Program data: TOkj7nevZ9ajdokFdaa++3ClOmo2VJcejdN2ejwdTCWlI0gyCI0b7dQwAAAAAAAAJ2JJlJ3xY+Ju087Sp7250a/aVj/ddAppdGel4drQGcLBxFiwAAAAADlpimIMAAAA",
"Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]",
"Program log: Instruction: Transfer",
"Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4736 of 164467 compute units",
"Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
"Program SW1TCH7qEPTdLsDHRgPuMQjbQxKdH2aBStViMFnt64f consumed 143542 of 299700 compute units",
"Program SW1TCH7qEPTdLsDHRgPuMQjbQxKdH2aBStViMFnt64f success"
]
}
},
"subscription": 1919
}
}

How i can turn this data to like solscan's transfers table?
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these tables use the `preTokenBalances` and `postTokenBalances` fields when fetching a transaction with `getTransaction`. You can see how they're defined at https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction